# Debian - Wireguard Forces Real Time Kernel

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, wireguard, realtime

I've a system running Debian 12 and while trying to install Wireguard I noticed it would pull a different kernel:

```
root@iotgateway:~# apt install wireguard --no-install-recommends
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-6.1.0-13-rt-amd64 linux-image-rt-amd64
Suggested packages:
  linux-doc-6.1 debian-kernel-handbook grub-pc | grub-efi-amd64 | extlinux
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-6.1.0-13-rt-amd64 linux-image-rt-amd64 wireguard
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
16 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/68.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 408 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ^C
```

**Is there a way to install and use Wireguard without installing the real time kernel?**

I would like to stay with my current "normal" kernel

`6.1.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.55-1 (2023-09-29)`.

Thank you.

Comment: 1/ you just need wireguard-tools /2 what would happen if you try `apt --no-install-recommends install wireguard linux-image-6.1.0-13-rt-amd64- linux-image-rt-amd64-` (the trailing minus asks for removal, so prevents installation)? Do you get any additional information then?

Comment: that is odd, none of my Debian 12's with wireguard did that

Comment: Found the problem. I was trying to install WG inside a LXC container and while the host had the WG kernel module it was running an older kernel version and somehow forcing the container to attempt to install a different kernel. I simply updated the host kernel and then it installed just fine without trying to pull another kernel... thanks anyways.

Comment: Ahh, details reveal the issue